# Symlink to current folder as absolute path without typing whole path

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, ln

Symlinks are saved shortcuts for relative paths:

```
~/foo➤ ln -s . ~/bar/foo
~/foo➤ ls -l ~/bar
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x    1 me  me     1B 15 May 14:38 foo -> .
```

The file `~/bar/foo` is a symlink to `bar`s current directory, i.e. itself

What if I want to create a symlink in another directory to the directory I'm in at the time? So in the above example, I'm in `~/foo` and I want to create `~/bar/foo` as a symlink to `~/foo`. Of course my current directory might be quite a bit longer than 5 characters and might not be so easy to type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say type

```
ln -s $PWD ~/bar/
```

or

```
ln -s `pwd` ~/bar/
```

You could use also

```
ln -s $PWD ~/bar/
```

but I guess you knew that and that is not what you are looking after. So please could you update your question to explain what's your goal?

If the path contains spaces, then it would be advisable to use:

```
ln -s "$PWD" ~/bar/
```

Comment: Double-quote your `$` variables and command substitutions, otherwise file names with spaces will muck up the run. You also don't need the ending `$(basename $PWD)` (and you've forgotten a `$` (and quoting :-) )) since that is the default link name anyway.

Comment: I think I was being stupid. I thought I tried the `pwd` approach and something went wrong. Let's put that down to an ID-ten-T error

Comment: @DanielAndersson you're right that it does not support spaces in path. Good point. so for the record I will update the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely:

```
ln -s "$(readlink -f .)" ~/bar
```

(might be good for generality in scripts) or just

```
ln -s ~/foo ~/bar
```

Relatively:

```
ln -s ../foo ~/bar
```

Tab completion will help you type.

---

From grawity's comment and http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils-announce/2012-03/msg00000.html:

> * Noteworthy changes in release 8.16 (2012-03-26) [stable]
>
> ...
>
> `ln` now accepts the `--relative` option, to generate a relative symbolic link to a target, irrespective of how the target is specified.

So with this version:

```
ln -s --relative . ~/bar
```

should work (with in practice is identical your first example, with the addition of the `--relative` switch).

Comment: Latest *coreutils* can automatically create relative symlinks using `ln -s -r foo ~/bar`.

Comment: @grawity: Interesting. Not on my system yet, apparently (Debian Sid).

Comment: It seems to have been added for v8.16 on March 22nd, according to git.

Comment: Also, what is the advantage of `$(readlink -f .)` over `$PWD`?

Comment: @grawity: Not much. They work differently if the current working directory has been reached by a link. `readlink -f` will then symlink to the absolute target path of the current directory, while `$PWD` will symlink to the literal directory one is currently in. What is wanted is probably different from time to time, and first and foremost probably not an issue at all.